# C++11 Templates Types

Tags: templates, c++11, types

```
template<int T>
struct TypeReturn{

        string Type() { return "int";}
};

int main() { cout << TypeReturn<int>::Type << endl;}
```

"error: redeclared here as ‘int T’
 struct TypeReturn{"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
struct TypeReturn;

template<>
struct TypeReturn<int>{

        static std::string Type() { return "int";}
};

int main() { cout << TypeReturn<int>::Type() << endl;}
```

FYI, why it works: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Comment: Nice, but you should complete your example with the generic implementation of Type(): `template<typename T>
struct TypeReturn
{ static std::string Type() {return "unknown";} };`